# Consume a and write a pdf from a webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, pdf

Iv been asked to consume a pdf from a webservice in java.The problem is I do not know how to write on to a file so that it can be well seen by pdf viewers.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/xcvbb/rest/integrationservices/getPDF");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/pdf");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

             //writing the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/dkimigho/Downloads/bitarraypdf.pdf");

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server2 .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                fileOutput.write(br.readLine().getBytes());
            }

            //closed the output stream
            fileOutput.close();
            ///
            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: get inputstream from HttpURLConnection object and write to a file having pdf extension.

Comment: You probably should take a look at iText or some other pdf library

Comment: Shiva I have tried it but its not working.an example of a code might be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I think you should use binary based i/o stream (ie. BufferedInputStream) rather than text based i/o stream (in case a line based reading mess up the encoding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use binary I/O to prevent the file from getting corrupted.
You don't need to use any library to copy files (as is) from any source.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/xcvbb/rest/integrationservices/getPDF");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/pdf");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + conn.getResponseCode());
}

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

//writing the downloaded data into the file we created
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/dkimigho/Downloads/bitarraypdf.pdf");

/* use binary I/O to prevent line based operation messing with the encoding.*/
byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
int b_read = 0;
while ( (b_read = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fileOutput.write(buf, 0, b_read);
}
fileOutput.flush();
//closed the output stream
fileOutput.close();
//
conn.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked